# Maven chamando Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant

Tenho um projeto maven, quero que o maven "chame" algumas target do ant, ja vi que tem um plugin "maven-antrun-plugin" la no site do apache, mas não conseguir entender nenhum exemplo, alguem poderia me dar um exemplo simples, tipo criando um .jar(eu sei que da pra fazer isso no maven)só para saber mais ou menos como funciona.

Comment: Usando o `maven-antrun-plugin` é possível referenciar um `build.xml` do *ant* e assim suas *targets*, já tentou isto?

Comment: Era isso que eu queria fazer, mas não achei um exemplo bom que der para eu entender, sabe de algum artigo ou algo do tipo, que possa me indicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o `maven-antrun-plugin` você pode usar um arquivo *ant* externo.

Como exemplo, vamos considerar este `build.xml` que contém um *target* para

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="stack-test">
    <target name="showJavaVersion">
        <exec executable="java">
            <arg value="-version" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

E referenciá-lo no *build* de nosso `pom.xml` da seguinte forma:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                        <target name="showJavaVersion" />
                    </ant>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Ao executarmos o *life cycle compile*(`mvn compile`) teremos uma saída parecida com esta:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-antrum-example 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ maven-antrum-example ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /usr/tmp/maven-antrum-example/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ maven-antrum-example ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (compile) @ maven-antrum-example ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:

showJavaVersion:
     [exec] java version "1.8.0_60"
     [exec] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
     [exec] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.228 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-19T16:49:59-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/368M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Usando diretamente no `pom.xml`, sem importar o `build.xml`, a configuração equivalente seria esta:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target name="showJavaVersion">
                    <exec executable="java">
                        <arg value="-version" />
                    </exec>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Cara era isso mesmo que eu queria, velho muuuuuito obrigado!!

Comment: Cara fiz o exemplo que vc pasou,vale realtar que uso um repositorio interno da empresa e que essses artifacts tem no repositorio so que em versões superiores, e saiu esse seguinte erro no console:

Comment: '[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (compile) on project ProjetoTeste: Execution compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run fa
e resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.4, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.4: Failure to
 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]'

Comment: @emanuelcavalcante olha o erro `Failure to was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`: isto é por que falhou por algum motivo, como acesso à repositórios e ficou com o cache local. Ou você força que seja baixado, ou apaga o cache. Já é outra coisa, se for preciso faça outra pergunta com mais informações

Comment: Então conseguir resolver o problema, a versão que antrun tava requerindo não tinha no meu repositorio local, então ele não podia ser executado, mas ja esta dando certo, vlw cara

Comment: @emanuelcavalcante ok, caso tenha sido útil considere aceitar a resposta como correta